# How to enable strict mode globally in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, strict-mode

I spent a lot of time debugging a program, thinking I couldn't do something when my only mistake was to having switched the case of a variable name.

I can enable strict mode (AKA, no undeclared variable can be used) per file by typing "use strict"; it indeed shows me that I am using a non-existing variable.

How can I enable strict mode globally, or at least for my project's files ?

Comment: It's not 'strict mode'. It's 'use strict'.

Comment: @D.Simon corrected, thanks you

Answer (score 1):

> Because strict mode is selected at the level of a syntactic source
>   text unit, strict mode only imposes restrictions that have local
>   effect within such a source text unit. Strict mode does not restrict
>   or modify any aspect of the ECMAScript semantics that must operate
>   consistently across multiple source text units.

That's what the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-strict-variant-of-ecmascript) says.

So it's not possible to globally enable strict mode for multiple JavaScript files.

However, you could use a build tool like Gulp. This enables you to combine all your JavaScript files to one single file. In this case, you would only have to enable the strict mode once.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```js
use strict
```

Please check the tutorial in w3schools.com 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Comment: This is what I'm doing on one file, and it works, but how can I enable it for the whole angular project ?

Comment: I forgot to include "globally" in the title, sorry.

Comment: Try to add this code in your index.html before including all angular files.

Comment: It seems to have worked, thanks you. Mind adding this to your answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

What about putting the 'use strict' in app.js as common file. Please make a try.

Answer (score 0):

Add **ng-strict-di** attribute to the body tag of your index.html

Here is the documentation: 
[AngularJs Strict Di Mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#strict-di-mode)